# ODBC Hive, Credential cache is empty

Tags: hive, odbc, kerberos, mit-kerberos

I got error "Credential cache is empty" during ODBC Hive tests. See full error detail

```
ODBC Hive - Test Results

[Cloudera][Hardy] (34) Error from server: SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure. Minor code may provide more information (Credential cache is empty).
```

Do you have any experience?

I tested different setting of MIT Kerberos in Windows e.g.:

- generate kerberos ticket, `kinit.exe -k -t app_store.keytab app_store@HW.PROD.BDP'`
- checked kerberos tickets in cache, `klist.exe`
- setup `KRB5CCNAME=C:\cache\krb5cache` and `KRB5_CONFIG=c:\ProgramData\MIT\Kerberos5\krb5.ini`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few possible issues:

- You have to check that krb5cache is file (not directory), it is important point
- The path to the cache have to be different for different person use this setting for variable  `KRB5CCNAME=%USERPROFILE%\krb5cache`
- You have to generate kerberos ticket before run ODBC Test, see
  `kinit.exe -k -t "c:\Apps\MIT\Kerberos\store.keytab" store@HW.PROD.BDP`